# How do I run a test case in Angular 6 Jasmine-Karma on a method that calls subscribe and returns data from an API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is my ts file, where I'm calling the method from ngOnInit, and getAllAccounts is where I'm fetching the API

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getAllAccounts();
}

getAllAccounts() {
  this.service.getAllAccounts().subscribe({
     next: (data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.allAccounts = data;
    }
     },
  });
}
```

This is my spec file where I'm trying to test the data being rendered

```
it("should test subscribe method is getting called", fakeAsync(() => {
   const accountSpy = spyOn(service, "getAllAccounts").and.returnValue(of(getAllAccountsList()));
   const subSpy = spyOn(service.getAllAccounts(), "subscribe");
   component.ngOnInit();
   tick(100);
   expect(accountSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   tick(300);
   expect(subSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
it("should test execution within subscribe method", fakeAsync(() => {
   component.ngOnInit();
   expect(component.allAccounts).toBeDefined();
   expect(component.allAccounts.length).toBeGreaterThan(5);
}));
```

Also, how do I test ngOnInit()?

Answer (score 0):

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` you call is when `ngOnInit` is called. That being said, it is no problem calling `ngOnInit` manually in a unit test. To test what you have, I would do:

```
it('should set allAccounts', () => {
   // spy on the service method and return an observable
   spyOn(service, "getAllAccounts").and.returnValue(of(getAllAccountsList()));
   component.ngOnInit();
   // assert that their lengths are the same
   expect(component.allAccounts.length).toBe(getAllAcountsList().length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I should have mentioned that getAllAcountsList is the mock data I created in the spec file, which has a length of two. How do I test this part ```next: (data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.allAccounts = data;
    }

Comment: We are testing that, no? We are asserting that the length of allAccounts is the same as the mock

Comment: No, we are asserting that the functions returns an api, but how do I test such a method?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question completely. When we assert that component.allAccounts.length is the same as the mock, that next method should have be traversed/travelled.

Comment: just looking at my ts file, the method getAllAccounts() is calling the service class which is calling an api from the backend (this.service.getAllAccounts().subscribe), how would you test this in the spec file?

Comment: I would personally test it how I have shown. We spy on the `getAllAccounts` of the spy and return a value. We should not be testing the actual implementation of the `service` because a unit test should assume all external things are working but is what I am about to test working? Meaning, if everything else works (service, etc.), does this component work?

Comment: component works fine. Thanks for all your help, will try your way shortly.